# SyntaxError: invalid syntax in Python Django

Tags: python, html, django, web, web-applications

I am currently using Python 3.4 with Django 1.10.3 to make a website that is basically an 'online notebook' where the user can store their notes (entries and respective topics).

My project's main folder directory is in
*C:\Users\Steven\mynotes*

My apps' folder directory is in
*C:\Users\Steven\mynotess*
(with **double s** -> I apologize for terrible naming. I'm a novice in web app development, and I don't want to go through the trouble changing the name right now)

So I was given this error in the command prompt when I ran the server.

```
`Unhandled exception in thread started by <function check_errors.<locals>.wrapper at 0x0465FB70>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 226, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 121, in inner_run
    self.check(display_num_errors=True)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 374, in check
    include_deployment_checks=include_deployment_checks,
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 361, in _run_checks
    return checks.run_checks(**kwargs)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\registry.py", line 81, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 14, in check_url_config
    return check_resolver(resolver)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 24, in check_resolver
    for pattern in resolver.url_patterns:
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 35, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 313, in url_patterns
    patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 35, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 306, in urlconf_module
    return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 109, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2254, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2237, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2226, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1200, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1129, in _exec
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1467, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1572, in get_code
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1532, in source_to_code
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 321, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\Steven\mynotes\urls.py", line 23
    ]
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax`
```

This is inside *mynotes/urls.py* (main project folder)

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin


urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls),
    url(r'', include('mynotess.urls', namespace= "mynotess")),
]
```

This is inside *settings.py*

```
ROOT_URLCONF = 'mynotes.urls'
```

This is inside *mynotess/urls.py* (apps folder)

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    #home page
    url(r'^$', views.index, name = 'index'),
    #topics page
    url(r'^topics/$', views.topics, name = 'topics'),
]
```

This is inside *views.py*. I have a Topic class and an Entry class in models.py. The Topic class has the attribute dateAdded (which is a timestamp)

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import Topic

def index(request):
    #home page
    return render(request, 'mynotess/index.html') #sends request to index.html template

def topics(request):
    #topics page
    topics = Topic.objects.order_by ('dateAdded')
    context = {'topics' : topics}
    return render(request, 'mynotess/topics.html', context)
```

Inside *mynotess/templates/mynotess/* I have three html files as follows:

*base.html* (the parent template)

```
<p> 
    <a href = "{% url 'mynotess:index' %}">My Notes</a> -
    <a href = "{% url 'mynotess:topics' %}">Topics</a>
</p>

{% block content %}{% endblock content %}
```

*index.html* (for the home page)

```
{% extends "mynotess/base.html" %}

{% block content %}
<p>My Notes allows you to take notes online without having to worry about them getting deleted when your computer crashes! Type in anything you want to remember,
including lecture notes, passwords, ANYTHING!</p>
{% endblock content %}
```

*topics.html* (for the topics page)

```
{% extends "mynotess/base.html" %}

{% block content %}

<p>Topics</p>

<ul>
{% for topic in topics %}
<li>{{topic}}</li>
{% empty %}
<li>No topics to show.</li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>

{% endblock content %}
```

localhost:8000 would not load up as a result. I really have no idea where I went wrong here. I think the error has something to do with the URLs, but I have no idea what exactly is wrong about it. Any sort of help would be HIGHLY appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: You are missing a close parenthesis on the line that includes the admin urls.

Comment: oh god! Thanks so much! I've been trying to debug this all night last night!

Comment: What text editor are you using? I'm using Sublime text with some plugins (everything is free) and it highlights syntax errors like that so you don't beat your head against the wall for hours trying to find a missing comma.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your url it should be `url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),`